# How to detect a sentence with only words and a period using regex?

Tags: python, regex

Sample Input

`['Hi my name is blank.', 'Do it 3 times.', 'Check out this website: https://blah.com', 'I like pie.', 'My email is asdf@jkl@gmail.com.']`

Sample Output

```
['Hi my name is blank.','I like pie']
```

How can I return words that use only words and end with a period?

This is the regex I am trying to use: `[A-Za-z]*.`

Comment: You can use this `[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*\s*\.` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eAU3Cy/1)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Or simply: `[A-Za-z\s]+\.`. (Adding space to your own attempt, escaping the `.` and changing quantifier to 1+.

Comment: @SamWhan: Your regex can match just some spaces and a dot which I wanted to avoid as that might not be what OP wants to match.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*\.?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EplFbN/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[a-zA-Z]+`: Match a word containing 1+ alphabets
- `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*`: Match 0 or more words separated by 1+ whitespaces
- `\.?$`: Match optional period before end

**Code:**

```
>>> list = ['Hi my name is blank.', 'Do it 3 times.', 'Check out this website: https://blah.com', 'I like pie.', 'My email is asdf@jkl@gmail.com.']
>>> reg = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*\.?$')
>>> print (filter(reg.match, list))
['Hi my name is blank.', 'I like pie.']
```